# how to convert cgal polygon to combinatorial map

Tags: c++, fedora, cgal

I'm creating an application reads .off files as polygon using cgal and preview it ,As the following example:
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/Polyhedron_2draw_polyhedron_8cpp-example.html

how to use CGAL combinatorial map to add or remove vertices , AS the following example:
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Combinatorial_map/Combinatorial_map_2map_3_operations_8cpp-example.html

any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you read a polygon or a polyhedron ? If you want to use combinatorial map oeprations, and if you read a .off file; you can directly read the off into a Combinatorial map (instead of reading it into a polyhedron, then use a converter).

Comment: @gdamiand the program read  .off file as Polyhedron ,
I didn't found any reference to read .off file to combinatorial map

Comment: Note that you need a Linear cell complex as you have 3D points. And the example at https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Linear_cell_complex/index.html#Linear_cell_complexAutomaticAttributesManagement mentions a function CGAL::load_off()

Comment: @AndreasFabri thank you